# Routing traffic over Vpn without NAT?

Tags: linux, networking, security, vpn, iptables

I want to tunnel traffic through my vpn but I just realized that my kernel does not have nat enabled ;(

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.20.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables v1.4.14: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I dread compiling kernel at the moment, mostly becausde I am always out of luck with smooth afterwards. Anyway is there a way to route traffic through Vpn without Nat trick above? I searched around but my searches came out fruitless.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all: are you sure you're not just missing the module loaded?

Try:

```
modprobe iptable_nat
```

Otherwise: yes you could also do it without NAT by setting for the given network address a static route to the interface you want but this implies that also on the other side you have to do the same (actually opposite: publish a route for your network) routing aswell. And of course in this case all the hosts on both networks may be theoretically visible (which may or not be a positive thing depending on your needs)

Comment: fede.evol, it looks like I do not have nat in anyway;( I can probably define the manual routing on the server. But my client is Android so that is going to be sticky maybe. Can you please tell me the actual commands that I am looking for?